# Django - an equality check in annotate-clause

Tags: django

In my Django 1.9 project I am trying to output something like this:

```
return MyModel.objects.values(...).\
               annotate(flg = ExpressionWrapper(F('rgt') - F('lft') > 0, 
                        output_field = BooleanField()))
```

This yields `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'` error.

I try to rewrite it using `Case-when` syntax:

```
return MyModel.objects.values(...)\
              .annotate(flg = Case(When(F('rgt') - F('lft') > 0, then = True, 
               output_field = BooleanField())))
```

This time, I end up with `TypeError: __init__() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments` error. I am lost. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F

...

return MyModel.objects.values(...).\
               annotate(flg=ExpressionWrapper(Q(rgt=F('lft')), 
                        output_field=BooleanField()))
```

Feature request to make it easier: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27021

Comment: what is `Q` in your code?

Comment: @theV0ID I updated the snippet

Answer (score 4):

Django expressions don't support the comparison operators using standard syntax.

Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#supported-arithmetic

However, you can use `Func()` expressions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions

```
.annotate(flg=Func(F('rgt') + F('lft'), template='%(expressions)s > 0'))
```

Or even better, define a Function / Transform class:

```
class GreaterThanZero(Transform):
    template = '%(expressions)s > 0'

.annotate(flg=GreaterThanZero(F('rgt') + F('lft')))
```

Transforms are unary operators, extending `Transform` you can ensure that only one `expression` is passed as an argument. So that you couldn't do `GreaterThanZero(F('rgt') + F('lft'), 1, 2, 3, 14)`.

Obviously, a more flexible solution should allow to pass both sides of the comparison. Somethin like this:

```
class GreaterThan(Func):
    arg_joiner = '<'
    arity = 2
    function = ''

.annotate(flg=GreaterThan(F('rgt') + F('lft'), 0))
```

Comment: How would compare strings?

Comment: Here is a feature request https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27021 and it has an example how to it before it is implemented: `Model.objects.annotate(boolfield=ExpressionWrapper(Q(field__gte=4), output_field=BooleanField()))`

Answer (score 3):

Since "Django 4.0" you can do it with [**Exact** lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/lookups/#lookup-reference)

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.lookups import Exact

queryset.annotate(is_current=Exact(
    F('id'), F('user__account__current_subscription')
))
```

[Django commit with examples and testcases](https://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/f42ccdd835e5b3f0914b5e6f87621c648136ea36)

Comment: Provides false postitive results for strings. idk why.