# Annotate queryset with boolean where one field is equal or not to another field

Tags: django, django-orm

The question is regarding annotation in Django.

For example I have a following model:

```
class Example(models.Model):

    field_1 = PositiveIntegerField()
    field_2 = PositiveIntegerField()
```

And I want to annotate queryset based on this model with boolean `True` or `False` based on whether `field_1 == field_2`

I managed to find 2 solutions on this, both of that don't satisfy me.

1. `Example.objects.extra(select={'equal': r' field_1 = field_2'})`

Use Raw SQL, and `extra()` that is about to get deprecated.

2)

```
Example.objects.all()\
    .annotate(
    equal=
        Case(
            When(field_1=F('field_2'), then=True),
            default=False,
            output_field=BooleanField(),
        )
    )
```

Which is quite verbose and makes queryset 4 times slower.

Question is  - is it possible to express such logic in Django ORM without the usage of RAW SQL and with less verbose and more straightforward logic?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332304/django-an-equality-check-in-annotate-clause

Comment: @Tariq Yousef  .Thanks mate, it has helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this one here on Stackowerflow.

```
annotate(
            equal=ExpressionWrapper(
                Q(field_1=F('field_2')),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            ))
```